# nodej ejs conditional variable declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I've an `ejs` template as :

```
<div id="id1">
 do something
</div>
<div id="id2">
 do something
</div>
```

The value of `id` is decided from the backend `node.js` code. So the value of `id` is different from different values of certain variables that are rendered from backend. I'm trying to use `if-else` case as :

```
<% if(backendvalue== "F"){ %>
   var id1 = "F";
   var id2 = "A";


<% } else if (backendvalue == "N") { %>
   var id1 = "N";
   var id2 = "B";

<% } %>
```

and use the above declared variables as :

```
<div id="<%= id1%>">
  do something
</div>
<div id="<%= id2%>">
  do something
</div>
```

But i'm getting error as `id1` not defined. Is there any way i could sole this issue as i have 4 such variables and 3 different conditions and lots of html code which depends on those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of assigning is almost similar to the way you use the variable that is passed from the backend. You just need to remove the `=` symbol as :

```
<% v1= "value1"%>
```

The value of **v1** is now **value1** and can be used anywhere inside the ejs as :

```
<%= v1%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error makes sense because you are restricted the scope, to the `if {}`.

Just remove the `var`, they become global then.

```
<% if(backendvalue== "F"){ %>
     id1 = "F";
     id2 = "A";


<% } else if (backendvalue == "N") { %>
     id1 = "N";
     id2 = "B";

<% } %>
```